# how to resolve com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl class cast exception

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to retrieve mongodb document from a collection using the below code. But I am getting class cast exception.

```
DBCursor cursor = (DBCursor) collection.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", "theId")); 

console Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBCursor.
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor` should be a `FindIterable`.  `DBCursor` is the old API.  If `collection` is a `MongoCollection` you need to use the new API everywhere.  Mixing and matching is almost certainly not going to work most of the time.

Comment: Also, if you still want to use `DBCursor` then you need to use `DBCollection` collection rather than `MongoCollection`.